# How to find all build events in my solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My solution contains a lot of projects, After build a specific directory will be created in "bin" but I do not know, which build event in which project makes it.

Is there any way to trace or find all build events in my solution?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Output window? There you'll see what is happening during building

Comment: Why you do not check Projects output path for short? Rightclick on Project->Build --> Outputpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it with help of powerShell. For example I have huge solution, and one of its project write pre- and post- events:

[image: BuildEvents]

All build events are stored in project files in text mode
[image]

So you can simple open powershell in solution folder and enter command:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "PreEvent" | group path | select name
```

and result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the build path of each project in the confifuration page of your project: right click of your project -> Settings

This will look like this [image]

I have a german Visual Studio 2017. It'll look the same in other versions. 
You can set output path as relative or absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Build -> Clean Solution
2. Open Output window (View -> Output or Ctrl+Alt+O)
3. Start building your solution from scratch (Build -> Build Solution or Ctrl+Shift+B)

And look at the Output Window:
[image]